# ios7 delete photos not work

Tags: ios7, alassetslibrary

I need to delete the system photo on iOS7,this my code , but not work

Photos.framework Only support iOS8 above.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
      {
          if([[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyAssetURL] isEqual:assetURLs] )
          {
              [asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
              {
                  NSLog(@"assetURL : %@",assetURLs);
                  NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
              }];
          }
      }];
}
failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
  {
      NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
  }];
```

log:

> assetURL : assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=BAEEADAF-A1E6-4DBB-BD5A-07058B671AE2&ext=PNG
>
> **Error : Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3300 "Write failed" UserInfo=0x14edf940 {NSLocalizedDescription=Write failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x14eb7580
>
> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain error -3300.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset because the write failed.}**

Answer (score 0):

The new Photos framework provides the following method for previously stored ALAsset URLS:

```
+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(PHFetchOptions *)options
```

From the Apple Docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class)

The Assets Library framework is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and later, replaced by the Photos framework. Use this method if your app has previously stored URLs from ALAsset objects and you need to retrieve the corresponding Photos framework objects.